# Finding nearest value in a SortedDictionary

Tags: c#, collections, dictionary, sorteddictionary

I have a SortedDictionary

```
 SortedDictionary<int, CPUOptimizationObject> myDict;
```

Now I want to find the first value above X.
I can do something like this

```
foreach (var iKey in MyDict.Keys)
{
   if (iKey >= thresholdKey)
   {
       foundKey = iKey;
       break;
   }
}
```

but this isn't good performance wise.
Any better suggestion?
(is there a method for that in the collections  something like Binary search for SortedDictionary ?)

Comment: Using a double as key is not a good idea. What are you storing there and why are you using a SortedDictionary if you are looking for the nearest match? What's the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: You could call ToList() and then do BinarySearch or LINQ. But not sure if thats faster. Maybe you can improve your engineering for a better key or other listtype like Panagiotis already said.

Comment: you are correct about the double. fixed to int.

Comment: the double is in an historical piece of code and is translated from 3 characters string. changed it in the question but question remains

Comment: You cannot use a `BinarySearch` since the [`KeyCollection`-class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132259(v=vs.110).aspx) does not implement `IList`(as an array or list) so it does not allow random access. So i doubt that you can improve it easily.

Comment: See this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12412869/efficiently-find-nearest-dictionary-key)

Answer (score 7):

While, in theory, finding the smallest item that is larger than a given value is an operation that can be performed efficiently on a Binary Search Tree (which is what a `SortedDictionary` is implemented as) `SortedDictionary` does not expose the means for you to perform such a search on that data type.

You would need to use a different implementation of a Binary Search Tree in order to efficiently perform such a search, while still using the same type of data structure.  There are no suitable .NET types; you would need to use a 3rd party implementation (of which there are quite a few out there).

Answer (score 0):

You could try if this is faster. But I guess it will be faster only if you are performing the search multiple times.

```
var keys = new List<int>(myDict.Keys);
int index = keys.BinarySearch(thresholdKey);
```

Comment: This will most certainly be slower, without question, unless you're performing multiple searches.

Answer (score 0):

create a temp list n   using a  .toList() on your Sorteddictionary
Now since that results a List n
you could do

```
  n.Find(item =>item >20)
```

to retrieve  the first key in return that matches,

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this has better performance than the foreach, but this should work:

```
var foo = myDict.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Key > thresholdKey);
```

Comment: This is shorter to type, but it's going to do almost exactly the same thing.