# Searching sorted doubles for inequalities in .net

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, sorting, binary-tree

Folks,

Given a set of sorted values (perhaps in a List<T>, SortedList<T,K>, etc.) what's the best way to go about evaluating inequalities (greater-than, less-than, greater-than-or-equal-to, less-than-or-equal-to a given value)?  Possible with any of the standard .net types?  Or easily coded up?  Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

**EDIT** - of course I'm trying to make this as fast as possible.  needs to be highly performant

Comment: This question doesn't make sense.

Comment: how so?  I think its pretty simple.  I have a sorted list of doubles.  I want to find all values in the list that are greater than a given value, say 10.  one way to do this is to traverse the entire list.  but its sorted.  so I should be able to do faster.

Comment: why don't you query the collection using linq ?

Comment: because linq is slow.  it doesn't take advantage of the fact that the list is sorted.

Comment: btw, I could use LINQs TakeWhile, but I want to find values faster than that.

Comment: @SFun28: Because it's trivial. Use a binary search. Any time you have a sorted list, binary search should come to mind.

Comment: @Jason: don't be too hard... ;) IMO he knows a binary search fits his needs, but he asked to be sure and to know if there's something already implemented in .NET...

Comment: @SFun28, the algorithm you accept it as answer is O(n)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean something  like the good-old `lower_bound`/`upper_bound` functions on C++ `map<>`, AFAIK there's nothing built-in in C#.
On `List<T>` there's a [`BinarySearch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3f90y839.aspx) method implemented, but it works on exact matching only.

Anyway, you can easily implement it by yourself, peraphs using the code in this question as an example:
[Is there a Lower Bound function on a SortedList<K ,V>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594518/is-there-a-lower-bound-function-in-c-on-a-sortedlist)

Comment: I think that's gonna work!  I'll respond back once I've implemented.  thanks for the pointer!!!