# Does .NET have an existing binary search class for KeyValuePair<K,V>

Tags: c#, .net, binary-search

In my Unity3d application, I need to detect a polyline that has been selected by a user. The easy way to determine this is to add a collider component to each GameObject (polyline) then I'll know whenever the user clicks a polyline. But this is incredibly inefficient because I will have thousands of polylines.

So my more efficient method is to store each polylines distance from the point (0,0,0) in a `List <KeyValuePair<double,GameObject>>`. This list will be ordered from lowest distance to highest. When the user selects a point in the game, I will determine this points' distance (D) from (0,0,0) then use a 'Upper Bounds' `Binary Search` to find the polyline closest to this point (ie, with a similar distance to (0,0,0)).

**My Question:** Before I go and reinvent the wheel and code my own 'Upper Bounds' Binary Search algorithm, element sorting and etc, is there a C# .NET class for Upper Bounds Binary Search that will sort and search for me?

I am aware of the method `List(T).BinarySearch()` but is it up to me to ensure that the `List` is sorted correctly? If my list isn't sorted, and the method needs to sort the list each method call then that could be rather inefficient.

Comment: Just to confirm your last paragraph, from MSDN: "The List<T> must already be sorted according to the comparer implementation; otherwise, the result is incorrect."

Comment: Have you tried using `SortedList<TKey, TValue>`/`SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>`? From MSDN: 'The SortedList<TKey, TValue> generic class is an array of key/value pairs with O(log n) retrieval'. Though note that only unique keys can be inserted.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `SortedList<double, GameObject>` to store your polygons sorted instead of `List <KeyValuePair<double,GameObject>>`  . Or you Sort() your `List<>` once after all polygons have been added (the second option is the best if you are not going to add other polygons latter, obviously).

@LeakyCode [provided an implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594518/is-there-a-lower-bound-function-in-c-sharp-on-a-sortedlist) of lower bound for an `IList`, which would give you the index (in your list) of the closest `GameObject`  :

```
private static int BinarySearch<T>(IList<T> list, T value)
{
    if (list == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("list");
    var comp = Comparer<T>.Default;
    int lo = 0, hi = list.Length - 1;
    while (lo < hi) {
            int m = (hi + lo) / 2;  // this might overflow; be careful.
            if (comp(list[m], value) < 0) lo = m + 1;
            else hi = m - 1;
    }
    if (comp(list[lo], value) < 0) lo++;
    return lo;
}

public static int FindFirstIndexGreaterThanOrEqualTo<T,U>
                          (this SortedList<T,U> sortedList, T key)
{
    return BinarySearch(sortedList.Keys, key);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should you sort your list first using `List<T>.Sort` Method and implement our own `IComparer<T>` in a class. I think it's the best approach.

[References to IComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
[Reference to ISort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/234b841s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)