# How to get the nearest key to a specified number in a dictionary?

Tags: c#, math, dictionary

I have an Excel function which I'm trying to translate to C# equivalent code. The function (in Excel) is as follows:

```
WorksheetFunction.VLookup(number, Range("numberDictionary"), 2, True)
```

Essentially what this function does is...

Assuming a dictionary exists, defined as follows:

```
Number | Value
1      | 2
3      | 8
9      | 1
```

And assuming that my parameter 'number' equals 2

I would expect a Value returned of **8**, as the lookup function would round my input number 2 up to the nearest number in the range (3) and then return the associated value.

Can anyone tell me how I might achieve the same thing in C# code? Assuming the use of a `Dictionary<int, int>()`

Many thanks in advance

Ian

Comment: @HimBromBeere In this case the function would round UP to the nearest key

Comment: You could use an ordered collection and a binary search algorithm. If you insist on a dictionary that would be `O(n)` since you have to look at all keys.

Comment: What happens if the `number` is 10 (basically a number that is higher than the highest key)?

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the `Keys` property of `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, int> { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 8 }, { 9, 1 } };
var key = dictionary.Keys.Where(a => a >= 2).OrderBy(a => a).First();
var value = dictionary[key];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on a dictionary you could use following LINQ query:

```
Dictionary<int, int> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, int>() { 
    {1,2} ,{3,8} ,{9,1} 
};

int searchKey = 2;
int value;

if (dictionary.ContainsKey(searchKey))
    value = dictionary[searchKey];
else
{
    int nearestKey = dictionary.Keys
        .Select(i => new { Value = i, Diff = Math.Abs(i - searchKey) })
        .OrderBy(x => x.Diff)
        .ThenBy(x => x.Value > searchKey ? 0 : 1) // in case of ties you want the higher number
        .Select(x => x.Value)
        .First();
    value = dictionary[nearestKey];
}
```

this would be `O(n)` since you have to look at all keys. If you could use an ordered collection and a binary search algorithm it would be `O(log n)`. So you could use a [`SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c(v=vs.110).aspx)  or [`SortedList<TKey, TValue>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319(v=vs.110).aspx). [Differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935621/whats-the-difference-between-sortedlist-and-sorteddictionary)

With a `SortedList` you could use [this extension method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/594528/284240). Then it's simple:

```
int index = dictionary.FindFirstIndexGreaterThanOrEqualTo(2);
int value = dictionary[dictionary.Keys[index]];
```

Comment: Your method is O(N*log(N)) as you're sorting the entire set just to search for one value.

Comment: @Servy: what method do you refer to? My second approach presumes that OP uses a `SortedList` in the first place. I also didn't know that performance was a key criterion for OP.

Comment: I'm referring to the original revision, where you suggest sorting the entire contents of the dictionary just to find one value.

Comment: @Servy: you have commented 5 minutes after i've edited my answer. Feel free to provide a more efficient approach.  I'm sure there is one.

Answer (score 0):

```
        var input = 2;
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, int> { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 8 }, { 9, 1 } };

        var smallestDifference = int.MaxValue;
        var keys = new List<int>();

        if (dictionary.ContainsKey(input))
        {
            return dictionary[input];
        }

        foreach (var entry in dictionary)
        {
            var difference = entry.Key - input;
            if (difference < smallestDifference)
            {
                smallestDifference = difference;
                keys = new List<int>() { entry.Key };
            }
            else if (difference == smallestDifference)
            {
                keys.Add(entry.Key);
            }
        }

        var candidates = dictionary.Where(x => x.Key == smallestDifference).ToList();
        if ( candidates.Count == 1)
        {
            return candidates.SingleOrDefault();
        }
        return candidates.SingleOrDefault(y => y > input);
```