# The function cannot detect intersections of two curves

Tags: c#, intersection, curve, line-intersection

The below source code is supposed to find an intersection between two curves.

However, the function is unable to detect the intersection point.

How can I fix it?

[image]

```
using MathNet.Numerics.Interpolation;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public static Vec2 FindIntersectionOfTwoCurves(List<double> xList1, List<double> yList1,
                                               List<double> xList2, List<double> yList2)
{
    if (xList1 == null || yList1 == null || xList2 == null || yList2 == null ||
        xList1.Count != yList1.Count || xList2.Count != yList2.Count)
        return null;

    IInterpolation interpolation1 = Interpolate.Linear(xList1, yList1);
    IInterpolation interpolation2 = Interpolate.Linear(xList2, yList2);

    double lowerBound = Math.Max(xList1.Min(), xList2.Min());
    double upperBound = Math.Min(xList1.Max(), xList2.Max());

    double step = (upperBound - lowerBound) / 1000; // adjust the step size as needed
    for (double x = lowerBound; x <= upperBound; x += step)
    {
        double y1 = interpolation1.Interpolate(x);
        double y2 = interpolation2.Interpolate(x);

        if (Math.Abs(y1 - y2) < 1e-7)
        {
            return new Vec2(x, y1);
        }
    }

    return null;
}

public class Vec2
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }

    public Vec2(double x, double y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your step divisor (1000) and epsilon value (1e-7) aren't even the same order of magnitude given the range of slopes that may occur in your functions.  You're going to miss finding a solution if you only divide x horizontally to one part in 1000 but expect y vertically to be within one part in 10000000  (1e-7) given that the slope of the function may be quite high or even vertical (you have a parametric definition of your curve where (x,y)'s are given in an array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you are trying to find an intersection of two curves with a non-continous first derivative you should use the [Bisection method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method).

a quickly written C# implementation is as follows, the implementation of binary search is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594518/is-there-a-lower-bound-function-on-a-sortedlistk-v), the binary search can be replaced by a simpler linear interpolation if `X` is linearly spaced.

```
namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    public class LinearInterpolator
    {
        private static int BinarySearch<T>(Span<T> list, T value)
        {
            if (list == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("list");
            var comp = Comparer<T>.Default;
            int lo = 0, hi = list.Length - 1;
            while (lo < hi)
            {
                int m = (hi + lo) / 2;  // this might overflow; be careful.
                if (comp.Compare(list[m], value) < 0) lo = m + 1;
                else hi = m - 1;
            }
            if (comp.Compare(list[lo], value) < 0) lo++;
            return lo;
        }

        private static int FindFirstIndexGreaterThanOrEqualTo<T>
                                  (T[] sortedList, T key)
        {
            return BinarySearch(sortedList, key);
        }

        double[] x_values;
        double[] y_values;
        public LinearInterpolator(List<double> x, List<double> y)
        {
            // quick argsort
            int[] indicies = x.AsEnumerable().Select((v, i) => new { obj = v, index = i }).OrderBy(c => c.obj).Select(c => c.index).ToArray();
            x_values = indicies.Select(i => x[i]).ToArray();
            y_values = indicies.Select(i => y[i]).ToArray();
        }

        public double Interpolate(double x)
        {
            int index = FindFirstIndexGreaterThanOrEqualTo(x_values, x);
            if (index == 0)
            {
                return y_values[0];
            }
            double y1 = y_values[index - 1];
            double y2 = y_values[index];
            double x1 = x_values[index - 1];
            double x2 = x_values[index];
            return (x - x1) / (x2 - x1) * (y2 - y1) + y1;
        }

    }

    class IntersectionFinder
    {
        public static Nullable<(double, double)> FindIntersectionOfTwoCurves(List<double> xList1, List<double> yList1,
                                                   List<double> xList2, List<double> yList2)
        {
            if (xList1 == null || yList1 == null || xList2 == null || yList2 == null ||
                xList1.Count != yList1.Count || xList2.Count != yList2.Count)
                return null;

            LinearInterpolator interpolator1 = new LinearInterpolator(xList1, yList1);
            LinearInterpolator interpolator2 = new LinearInterpolator(xList2, yList2);

            double lowerBound = Math.Max(xList1.Min(), xList2.Min());
            double upperBound = Math.Min(xList1.Max(), xList2.Max());

            if (lowerBound > upperBound) // X axes don't overlap
            {
                return null;
            }

            double diff_start = interpolator1.Interpolate(lowerBound) - interpolator2.Interpolate(lowerBound);
            double diff_end = interpolator1.Interpolate(upperBound) - interpolator2.Interpolate(upperBound);

            if ((diff_start > 0 && diff_end > 0) || (diff_start < 0 && diff_end < 0)) // intersection doesn't exist
            {
                return null;
            }

            double mid = (lowerBound + upperBound) / 2;
            double diff_mid = interpolator1.Interpolate(mid) - interpolator2.Interpolate(mid);

            int iterations = 0;
            while (Math.Abs(diff_mid) > 1e-7)
            {
                if (diff_start > diff_end) // list1 is higher
                {
                    if (diff_mid > 0) // mid is also higher, intersection in right side
                    {
                        lowerBound = mid;
                        diff_start = diff_mid;
                    }
                    else // mid is lower, intersection in left side
                    {
                        upperBound = mid;
                        diff_end = diff_mid;
                    }
                }
                else // list 2 is higher
                {
                    if (diff_mid < 0)
                    {
                        lowerBound = mid;
                        diff_start = diff_mid;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        upperBound = mid;
                        diff_end = diff_mid;
                    }
                }
                mid = (lowerBound + upperBound) / 2;
                diff_mid = interpolator1.Interpolate(mid) - interpolator2.Interpolate(mid);
                iterations++;
                if (iterations > 10000) // prevent infinite loop if Y is discontinuous
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }

            return new(mid, interpolator1.Interpolate(mid));
        }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<double> xList1 = [1, 1.5, 2, 3.5, 4];
            List<double> xList2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
            List<double> yList1 = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8];
            List<double> yList2 = [8, 6, 4, 2, 0];
            Console.WriteLine(IntersectionFinder.FindIntersectionOfTwoCurves(xList1, yList1, xList2, yList2).ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

```
(2.5999999940395355, 4.799999992052714)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This small change can fix your problem. Don't watch for `Math.Abs(y1 - y2)` to be less than some epsilon (e.g. `1e-7`). Instead, watch for the sign of `y1 - y2` to change so that it's different from the previous iteration.  That is called looking for a *zero-crossing*.

For example:

```
int? prevSign = null;
for (double x = lowerBound; x <= upperBound; x += step) {
    double y1 = interpolation1.Interpolate(x);
    double y2 = interpolation2.Interpolate(x);
    int sign = Math.Sign(y1 - y2);
    if (prevSign.HasValue) {
        if (sign != prevSign.Value) {
            return new Vec2(x, y1);
        }
    } else {
        prevSign = sign;
    }
}
```

Comment: Let it be known that I don't approve of the asker's incremental linear scan for a solution.  One should be bisecting to find a root or using an existing root solver implementation.  But this answer keeps the original approach and provides a simple change to the original code to remedy the problem.

Comment: it depends, if you are doing this where both arrays are < 100 elements a linear search is faster, at about 100 elements it doesn't matter anymore, and for over 100 elements you should be using bisection, for this solution you just need to do a final linear interpolation to get a more accurate intersection.

Comment: the reason why a linear search might be faster with < 100 elements is because of branch prediction and SIMD, the computer tends to optimize the linear search too well, while a binary search has the cpu waiting on the ALU most of the time.

Comment: @AhmedAEK Absolutely not.  The solution can be found in the exact amount of time it takes the interpolator to evaluate the function once.  The interpolator has to locate the value where x appears in the array, it could locate the zero-crossing instead.  In other words, instead of searching for (x,y) where x is provided, you can search for (x,y) where y is provided.

Comment: the linear search with avx512 and floats can nearly do one element per cpu cycle, while each iteration of the binary search has to wait for the result to be computed (roughly 10 cycles per iteration), you get no vectorization or branch prediction, at least not out of the box, there are ways to make it faster though